# How to design a flow in bazel instead of using externalscripts

Tags: devops, bazel, bazel-rules

I am new to bazel.

I have some scripts which runs bazel command, also some pre and post commands for the env like files copy and installation as pre step and copy the files from the bin as post step.

For this a super script is written which will go to each dir and run this scripts.

I want to converthis fully to bazel.

Like I have to give a target, which then executes an actual targets to create the files.

Also want to run the pre and post steps for each target in the flow.

I searched but everyone says use the `cc_binary` which creates another binary, I don't want to use this.

Flow like

- A_Target
  --sub1_forA
  --pre_sub1_forA
  --sub1_forA command (Target)
  --Post- (Copying the bin files & cleaning)
  --Sub2_forB
- B_Targer

[The actual flow is as this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phLKu.png)

I saw `alias` can be but not able to understand how to use this for the desired flow and pre and post steps

INFO: Also to add I want to use this in windows environment too